# What's an efficient way to convert month and year string to a date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have column with **varchar** values like "022008" that I need to convert into a **datetime** like "02/01/2008". This will run on millions of records for a conversion process. What is an efficient select statement for doing this?

Comment: will your string always be of form "%mm%yyyy"?

Comment: yes, it will always be 6 characters, month first, then year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY
GO
Select StringValue, Cast(Stuff(StringValue, 3, 0, '-01-') As datetime)
From Table...
```

On a million rows on my local machine, that returned in 10 seconds.

Comment: +1: Correct, and nice use of STUFF (SQL Server 2005+ supported) command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Stuff was supported in SQL Server 2000, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

The STR_TO_DATE function does just what it sounds like it would do: it takes a string, and turns it into a standard date object. To get it into the MM/DD/YYY format, you use DATE_FORMAT. This is the simplest way to do this, and is probably the most efficient.

For your example, you can convert it like so:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('022008', '%m%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y');
-> 02/00/2008
```

You'll have to do some extra nonsense to get the day to read "01", so perhaps you could clean this up once you get the results back; otherwise, the query becomes more complicated.

Hope this helps.
-tjw

Comment: Seems like we're looking for MS Transact-SQL, though.  And "efficient" is the word that makes this a tough one...

Comment: This is valid for MySQL, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Not hugely efficient, but my first stab at it:

```
declare @s as char(6)
set @s = '031977'

select dateadd(month, cast(substring(@s, 1, 2) as int) - 1, dateadd(year, substring(@s, 3, 4) - 1900, 0))
```

**Output:**

```
1977-03-01 00:00:00.000
```